# spring social Facebook - single Facebook Instance

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-mvc, spring-social

I just created a project using latest spring social and spring social Facebook (and spring boot).

I'm trying to implement a Facebook signup which works fine except that it returns the same connection/profile for the first connected user every time.

My Facebook Profile Controller is:

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/unsecure/facebook")
public class FacebookProfileController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1895700328147293496L;

    @Autowired
    private Facebook facebook;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Result<FBUserVO> getUserFBProfile() {
        if (!facebook.isAuthorized()) {
            return ResultFactory.getFailResult("Facebook signup failed!");
        }
        FBUserVO user = FBUserToFBUserVO.INSTANCE.apply(facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList<Reference> friends = facebook.friendOperations().getFriends();
        if (!friends.isEmpty()) {
            user.setFriendsMessage("You have " + friends.size() + " friends playing. Join Now!");
        }
        return ResultFactory.getSuccessResult(user);
    }
}
```

This works the first time... after that it will return the same profile info every time even though when I'm debugging the FacebookTemplate class, this is created using a new/valid access_token for a new user but for some reason the URLs are created maybe using the old token. I tried debugging the urls but they don't seem to send any access token.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Can I get the current connection in another way?

Comment: Have you debugged the access token the second time to make sure that a new session has been created?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the ConnectionRepository class (which allows to remove the existing connection to Facebook provider for the first logged user which cause your problem).

Use a constructor like this and eliminate the Facebook autowiring:

```
private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;
    @Inject
    public FacebookProfileController(ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }
```

through the connectionRepository instance you can get the Facebook object for the current logged user by doing:

```
connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class).getApi()
```

***Note: To check if a user is not authenticated, you need to use:***

```
connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class)==null
```

When you finish to extract data for the current logged user, you have to use the instruction below in order to delete the persistent connection created through constructor:

```
connectionRepository.removeConnections("facebook");
```

Hope this helps!